# How to generate control number for every input "CN202201" in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

How can I concatenate the "CN2022" with "01", and for every insert it will increase +1? e.g CN202202, CN202203 ...

```
Example output:

CN202201,x,12,x,x@gmail.com
CN202202,x,12,x,x@gmail.com
CN202203,x,12,x,x@gmail.com
```

I'm assuming I will use something like this `CONCAT('CN2022', LPAD(id, 2, '0')) AS Control_Number` how can I declare it in a query that for every INSERT the Control_Number will be concatenated and for every insert it will increase by 1?

Comment: what database are you using

Comment: @nbk I'm using ms sql

Comment: what happens on the 100th row?